# Fill web form, Dynamic table with drop down menu

Tags: html, vba, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have pretty basic knowledge with HTML coding in VBA, I am trying to make a code which fills this webpage https://www.tesoreria.cl/CertificadosWeb/CertificadoRol/InicioMovRol?RUT=0&DV=0&EMAIL= . My code can select from the first drop down menu, and complete the bottom 2 text forms, the problem is the second drop down menu depends on the selection of the first one, and even though I give it an option based on a value, the options don't appear until I click and select manually from the first menu. If I just complete it using VBA the second menu options do not appear.

```
Sub Llenar()

Dim IE As Object
Dim region As Object
Dim comuna As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.tesoreria.cl/CertificadosWeb/CertificadoRol/InicioMovRol?RUT=0&DV=0&EMAIL="

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set region = IE.document.getElementById("region")

For i = 1 To region.Options.Length
    If region.Options(i).Text = "REGION METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO" Then
        region.selectedIndex = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Set comuna = IE.document.getElementById("comunas")

For j = 1 To comuna.Options.Length
    If comuna.Options(j).Text = "Lampa" Then
        comuna.selectedIndex = j
        Exit For
    End If
Next j

IE.document.getElementById("rol").Value = "187"
IE.document.getElementById("subrol").Value = "150"

End Sub
```

I get an error during the second For, saying Object required, probably because no options have been loaded. I tried using `.GetElementById("comunas").Value = "78"` to give the value directly but it does not work, it asks me to select a "comuna" from the second drop down menu.

Comment: What is `GetElemendById`? Did you mean `GetElementById`?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I used the correct syntax when running the code